# adding a function causes the code to stop without an error. (PHP/HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, php

My friends and I are working on a project and there's a part where we connect to a database, take some info from it and then displaying an image relevant to each part of the data. (More specific, we take flower names and put an image of each flower.)
After that we want to be able to change the html code in order to display some info about it.
The problem is that whenever we add a function (Change()) the code doesn't work. It doesn't matter where I put it or what it contains, the result is the same.

the code: (note that it doesn't work without the onclick but I added that for easier understanding of what I'm trying to do)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

<?php

$servername = "sometrollhost.net";
$username = ".........";
$password = "*********"; //cencored those :P
$dbname = "/////////";

mysql_connect($servename, $username, $password);


mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( "Unable to select database");

$petalcolor = str_replace("pe", "", $_POST[PetalColor]);
$pistilcolor = str_replace("pi", "", $_POST[PistilColor]);

$sql = "SELECT name, petalcolor, pistilcolor FROM flower WHERE petalcolor='$petalcolor' AND pistilcolor='$pistilcolor' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);


?>
</head>
<body>

<?php

function Change(){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="iggy";
}

$i=0;

while($i < $num){
    $name = mysql_result($result, $i, "name");
    $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);
    echo '<img onclick="Change()" src="/info/' . $name . '.jpg" width="102" height="102">';
    $i++;
} ?>
<div id="test"> abcd
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing php and javascript, the `Change` function is a php function, but it uses javascript inside. Also, quit using the `mysql_` API, its deprecated and bad, take a look at `PDO` or `mysqli` instead for better database APIs.

Comment: onclick is javascript event handler .. and you added the function in php tag which is not available on javascipt. you should add a script tag to html and add function there

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing stuff here, the function change its javascript, and should not be included into your php tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="iggy";
}
</script>
```

And then the PHP code you are using.

Comment: would you mind showing me the proper way then?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function Change(){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="iggy";
}

$i=0;
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(){
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="iggy";
}
</script>

<?php

$i=0;
```

like others are saying, the Change function is a javascript function, not a php function

Answer (score 0):

Your Change() function is JavaScript code, but you've got it inside php tags. It needs to be in an HTML script tag.